# How to quicly revert a WSUS deadline timer

Tags: windows-update, wsus

One of my coworkers applied a deadline to some windows updates for 1:00 in the afternoon and applied it to our servers. This was intended only for our desktops.

Is there a ready way to kill the scheduled reboot other than shutting down the windows update service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the only solution to this perticular problem is to locate all the updates with the deadline applied, remove the deadline and do a gpupdate /force. 
There appears to be a pretty straight forward method to script this process with powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a GPO (or edit an existing one) that would stop the automatic reboot due to to updates and use the `gpupdate /force` command on each of the servers.

The option to set this can be found in Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update. You'll still get the annoying prompt to reboot the machine, however there won't be a countdown. It's called "No auto-restart for scheduled automatic updates installations"

If the shutdown timer starts you can use the `shutdown -a` command which should abort the reboot procedure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is already applied. I don't think it stops it if a deadline has passed however.